# Converting a React + Redux + MUI Menu to Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, electron

I am attempting to convert a web-based React + Redux + MUI app to Electron. The app has a main AppBar with multiple dropdown menus, with menu items which hook into the app's Redux store. So a fairly typical set-up for these technologies in partnership, but I'm struggling to understand how to translate this (if it's possible) to an Electron application menu.

So if I have a MUI MenuItem with a typical `onClick` handler, like this:

```
const [soneState, setSomeState] = useState();

const handleOnClick = (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  console.log(`The value is ${val}`);
  setSomeState(val);
}
```

What would be the equivalent for an Electron Menu? Assuming also that I am leveraging the Redux store, rather than local component state. A number of the handlers in the menu communicate with an Express server via `fetch`. I have been reading up on Electron inter-process communication via the `contextBridge`, but I'm not sure which side the Electron Menu comes in that equation. Can it leverage both the Redux store as well as talking to the Main process? I assume I can't make `fetch` calls from the Menu?

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I figured it out...

I can use the pattern described in the official docs [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-3-main-to-renderer) to create an API in my `preload.js`, which the app menu can then call into to send messages to the render process. So in `preload.js` I have:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
  loadSomeFile: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('load-some-file', callback),
})
```

Then I define my menu like this:

```
const { app, Menu, MenuItem, dialog, ipcMain } = require('electron');

module.exports = (window) => {
  return Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'File',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'About',
        },
        {
          label: 'Preferences',
        },
        {
          type: 'separator'
        },
        {
          label: 'Load Some File',
          click() {
            dialog.showOpenDialog({
              properties: ['openFile']
            })
            .then((fileObj) => {
              window.webContents.send('load-some-file', fileObj);
            })
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'separator'
        },
        {
          label: 'Exit',
          click() {
            app.quit()
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  ])
}
```

And in my `main.js` I have:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, } = require('electron');
const path = require("path");
const mainMenu = require("./app/main-menu");

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true
    }
  });
  win.loadURL("http://localhost:8080");
  return win;
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const win = createWindow();
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu(win));
});
```

Most of what I already have in my React/Redux/MUI frontend code can remain unchanged. But I need to access the api from the `window` object on the frontend, and listen to events coming from the Main process (like from the app menu).

```
window.api.loadSomeFile((event, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Tested it and it works well. Very little to actually change in my code.